# How to move users table from AspNetUsers in ASP.NET application in Keycloak server?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, keycloak, password-hash

I need to move users table with password hashes and other information in Keycloak, and configure same hashing algorithm that was in ASP NET app

Unfortunetely I did not try anything. I am asking you for any tips or recommendations

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.